# Httpclient returning blank api keys and client id keys

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Ok, the second pair of eyes time for some reason my property is always coming back null.

They keys described here are only for demo purchases and will not work other wise.

```
public class RoundTableAPIClient {
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
}
```

This is a class that I store all my API calls in

```
private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;    
public RoundTableAPIClient() {
     _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    if (ApiKey != null | ClientSecret != null)  {
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(Constants.ApiKey, ApiKey);
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(Constants.ClientSecret, ClientSecret);
    }
}
```

The values for ApiKey and Client secret are null in my stock controller I am passing them in

```
public class StockController : Controller    {
    private readonly IStringLocalizer<StockController> _localizer;
    RoundTableAPIClient apiClient;
    public StockController(IStringLocalizer<StockController> localizer)   {
        _localizer = localizer;
        apiClient = new RoundTableAPIClient();
    }
```

This is my get example where I am going to the api to get the data this function is contained withing my stock controller.

```
  public async Task<object> Get(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions) {
        List<Stock> _result = new List<Stock>();
        apiClient.DeveiceType = device.Desktop;
        apiClient.DeveiceType = device.Desktop;
        apiClient.ApiKey = "B538F53B-37F7-4564-B7C5-56AFF399252B";
        apiClient.ClientSecret = "8132ED0B-8F0B-4841-8BF4-CE8438AC0F3E";        
        _result =  await apiClient.GetStockFromApi();
        return DataSourceLoader.Load(_result, loadOptions);
    }

public async Task<List<Stock>> GetStockFromApi() {
   List<Stock> _result = new List<Stock>();
   var uri = new Uri(string.Format(ApiUrl + Constants.GetALlStock, string.Empty));
   var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            var byteArray = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            _result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Stock>>(content);
    }
        return _result.ToList();
}
```

Its here when I inspect my http client that the default headers are still bank I dont understand why that is the case.

**Edit 2**

Should I be doing it more like this?

```
public async Task<List<Stock>> GetStockFromApi(string ApiKey,string ClientSecret) {
   List<Stock> _result = new List<Stock>();
   var uri = new Uri(string.Format(ApiUrl + Constants.GetALlStock, string.Empty));

        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
        if (ApiKey != null | ClientSecret != null) {
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(Constants.ApiKey, ApiKey);
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(Constants.ClientSecret, ClientSecret);
        }

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var byteArray = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            _result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Stock>>(content);
        }

        return _result.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: That isn't a real client secret, is it?

Comment: @pquest no its not

Comment: @pquest only for demostration purposes

Answer (score 1):

You add the headers in the constructor on the condition that either ApiKey or ClientSecret is not null, but they will always be null at that stage. You probably want to give those default values, or add them as parameters in the constructor.